# how to fix the azure credential issue when work with powershell?

Tags: azure

when I try to provide access control to azure using powershell script, I got below error.

****Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzureRmAccount to set up your Azure credentials.****

please provide some solution.

Answer (score 1):

The error has told you, you need to login with [`Connect-AzureRmAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/connect-azurermaccount?view=azurermps-6.13.0) first to use `AzureRm` powershell module.

Besides, you should know the `AzureRM` module was deprecated, so I recommend you to use the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.6.0) module. Login with [`Connect-AzAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-2.6.0) and use the [`Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azps-2.6.0) command.